# Structuring a MySQl Database for a Blog to include "labels" or "tags"

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I want to encompass the idea of "labels" or "tags" for a rudimentary blog I'm building.

The "posts" table looks like this:

```
table posts {
  post_id (autoincrement, int, primary key)
  post_text (text)
  published (boolean)
  timestamp (timestamp)
  published_date (date)
  user_id (varchar)
}

table labels {
      post_id
      label (varchar)
      label_id (autoincrement, int, primary key)
}
```

Is this the best approach?

The main 'problem' I see with this approach is when inserting a new post, because `post_id` is auto incrementing in the table `posts` you don't *technically* know the `post_id` to insert into `labels` at the moment of insertion. Doesn't seem like the most efficient solution.

Is there a way to link two tables...?

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to allow for common labels? You shouldn't need the `label_id` column with your current structure since `post_id` and `label` should be enough to make the row unique (unless you want to be able to label a post with the same label twice, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you don't technically know the post_id to insert into labels at the moment of insertion

Sure you do, it's in `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, or from your PHP code, [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). As soon as you make the `INSERT` query for the post, you know the ID generated and can use it when inserting your tags/labels. This is how you link the tables.

Comment: Whaddya know!? Thanks! So you'd recommend carrying out two separate queries. First, inserting values into posts, then retrieving the mysql_insert_id and inserting into the labels table?

Comment: That's not a recommendation, it's the only possible way. You cannot insert into multiple tables with a single `INSERT` query.